# React Component for editting data

Tags: reactjs, redux

after getting data from API  I want to show them into inputs,edit and update it in DB. I thought that beside the redux state, I should use also local state , but  some people here say that is not good practise .So how I can handle my **onChange** methods and how pass updated data into **axios.put** method???

```
class ArticleEdit extends Component {
     articleID = this.props.match.params.articleID; 

     state={
           title:'',
           text:'',
           imgs:[]
        }

onChange =(e)=>{}

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getArticleDetails(this.articleID);//get data from API
}

render() {
   return (
        <Fragment>
            {this.props.article===undefined?(<Spin/>):
                (
                <div >
                    <div >
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <Input name='title'
                                   value='this.props.article.title'  
                                    onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            <Textarea
                                name='text' 
                                value={this.props.article.title}
                                onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            <Button htmlType='submit'>Update</Button>
                        </Form>

                    </div>
                </div>
                )}    
        </Fragment>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    article: state.articleReducer.articles[0],    
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getArticleDetails}) 
                      (ArticleEdit);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how I can handle my onChange methods and how pass updated data into
>   axios.put method???

Well if that's literally what you want to do, then you can do it like this:

```
onChange = e => {
  try {
    const results = await axios.put(someurl, e.target.value)
    console.log('results', results)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('err', e)
  }
}
```

This will call axios.put after every keystroke - however, I doubt that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I used the static method **getDerivedStateFromProps**,which calls everytime when props  of your component has been changed.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    if(prevState.title===null && nextProps.article!==undefined){
        return{
            title:nextProps.article.title,
            text:nextProps.article.text
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

after that is easy to work with **onChange** method ,which just call this.setState().